# Using BNFC to determine a basic language for propositional logic (syntax error)

Tags: syntax, syntax-error, bnfc

I would like to parse sentences in propositional logic using BNFC. I wrote the following BNF grammar to facilitate this:

```
Negation.     N ::= "(" "-" L")";
Conjuction.   C ::= "(" L "&" L ")";
Disjuction.   D ::= "(" L "|" L ")";
Implication.  I ::= "(" L "=>" L ")";
Equivalence.  E ::= "(" L "<=>" L ")";
Atom.         L ::= Ident | N | C | D | I | E ;
```

However, with this construction I get the following error:

```
syntax error at line 6, column 27 before `|'
```

What is syntactically incorrect about the specification I provided?

#### Edit 1

Ok, so it looks like `bnfc` really does not like the idea of using the symbol `|` for union. How do I then assign multiple productions to a single rule, if not via a union? I do not want to have to define `Atom1. L ::= Ident ;`, `Atom2. L ::= N ;` and so forth, but is this necessary if I want this to work?

#### Edit 2

Ok, so giving different labels to each `L`-production, as in

```
Negation.     N ::= "(" "-" L")";
Conjuction.   C ::= "(" L "&" L ")";
Disjuction.   D ::= "(" L "|" L ")";
Implication.  I ::= "(" L "=>" L ")";
Equivalence.  E ::= "(" L "<=>" L ")";
Atom1.        L ::= Ident ;
Atom2.        L ::= N ;
Atom3.        L ::= C ;
Atom4.        L ::= D ;
Atom5.        L ::= I ;
Atom6.        L ::= E ;
```

allowed the file `logic.cf` to pass through `bnfc` without any errors. However, when the file is compiled using the command

```
bnfc -m -c file.cf
```

and I then try running `make`, I get the following error when Make tries to run `gcc` on the bnfc-generated file `Printer.c`:

```sh
gcc -g -W -Wall -c Absyn.c
flex -Plogic -oLexer.c logic.l
gcc -g -W -Wall -c Lexer.c 
Lexer.c:1477:16: warning: ‘input’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
     static int input  (void)
                ^~~~~
Lexer.c:1434:17: warning: ‘yyunput’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
     static void yyunput (int c, char * yy_bp )
                 ^~~~~~~
bison -t -plogic logic.y -o Parser.c
gcc -g -W -Wall -c Parser.c
gcc -g -W -Wall -c Printer.c
Printer.c: In function ‘ppL’:
Printer.c:289:20: error: ‘union <anonymous>’ has no member named ‘atom_’; did you mean ‘atom1_’?
     ppIdent(_p_->u.atom_.ident_, 0);
                    ^~~~~
                    atom1_
Printer.c:296:16: error: ‘union <anonymous>’ has no member named ‘atom_’; did you mean ‘atom1_’?
     ppN(_p_->u.atom_.n_, 0);
                ^~~~~
                atom1_
Printer.c:303:16: error: ‘union <anonymous>’ has no member named ‘atom_’; did you mean ‘atom1_’?
     ppC(_p_->u.atom_.c_, 0);
                ^~~~~
                atom1_
Printer.c:310:16: error: ‘union <anonymous>’ has no member named ‘atom_’; did you mean ‘atom1_’?
     ppD(_p_->u.atom_.d_, 0);
                ^~~~~
                atom1_
Printer.c:317:16: error: ‘union <anonymous>’ has no member named ‘atom_’; did you mean ‘atom1_’?
     ppI(_p_->u.atom_.i_, 0);
                ^~~~~
                atom1_
Printer.c:324:16: error: ‘union <anonymous>’ has no member named ‘atom_’; did you mean ‘atom1_’?
     ppE(_p_->u.atom_.e_, 0);
                ^~~~~
                atom1_
Printer.c: In function ‘ppInteger’:
Printer.c:336:31: warning: unused parameter ‘i’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 void ppInteger(Integer n, int i)
                               ^
Printer.c: In function ‘ppDouble’:
Printer.c:342:29: warning: unused parameter ‘i’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 void ppDouble(Double d, int i)
                             ^
Printer.c: In function ‘ppChar’:
Printer.c:348:25: warning: unused parameter ‘i’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 void ppChar(Char c, int i)
                         ^
Printer.c: In function ‘ppString’:
Printer.c:354:29: warning: unused parameter ‘i’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 void ppString(String s, int i)
                             ^
Printer.c: In function ‘ppIdent’:
Printer.c:360:28: warning: unused parameter ‘i’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 void ppIdent(String s, int i)
                            ^
Printer.c: In function ‘shL’:
Printer.c:507:20: error: ‘union <anonymous>’ has no member named ‘atom_’; did you mean ‘atom1_’?
     shIdent(_p_->u.atom_.ident_);
                    ^~~~~
                    atom1_
Printer.c:522:16: error: ‘union <anonymous>’ has no member named ‘atom_’; did you mean ‘atom1_’?
     shN(_p_->u.atom_.n_);
                ^~~~~
                atom1_
Printer.c:537:16: error: ‘union <anonymous>’ has no member named ‘atom_’; did you mean ‘atom1_’?
     shC(_p_->u.atom_.c_);
                ^~~~~
                atom1_
Printer.c:552:16: error: ‘union <anonymous>’ has no member named ‘atom_’; did you mean ‘atom1_’?
     shD(_p_->u.atom_.d_);
                ^~~~~
                atom1_
Printer.c:567:16: error: ‘union <anonymous>’ has no member named ‘atom_’; did you mean ‘atom1_’?
     shI(_p_->u.atom_.i_);
                ^~~~~
                atom1_
Printer.c:582:16: error: ‘union <anonymous>’ has no member named ‘atom_’; did you mean ‘atom1_’?
     shE(_p_->u.atom_.e_);
                ^~~~~
                atom1_
Makefile:42: recipe for target 'Printer.o' failed
make: *** [Printer.o] Error 1
```

I have no idea what this means. Why is it  trying to find `atom_`, when I've not specified such a thing in `logic.cf` If there are any people more experienced with the internals of `bnfc`, I wouldn't mind hearing from you.

#### Edit 3

Ok, so writing the labels as

```
Negation.     N ::= "(" "-" L ")";
Conjuction.   C ::= "(" L "&" L ")";
Disjuction.   D ::= "(" L "|" L ")";
Implication.  I ::= "(" L "=>" L ")";
Equivalence.  E ::= "(" L "<=>" L ")";
Atom.         L ::= Ident;
AtomN.        L ::= N ;
AtomC.        L ::= C ;
AtomD.        L ::= D ;
AtomI.        L ::= I ;
AtomE.        L ::= E ;
```

somehow magically allowed `make` to pass. However, my parser isn't exactly working, as something as simple as

```sh
echo "p" | ./Testlogic
```

returns with

```sh
error: line 1: syntax error at p
```

Isn't `p` a valid identifier, and so the production `Atom. L ::= Ident;` should allow it to pass? Why is this not the case?

Comment: hi, I am having same problem which is as long as use "|" it raises an error similar to yours. did you find any solution of correctly using "|"? :(

Answer (score 0):

It turns out BNFC is a bit picky, when it comes to the order of the productions. I had to write

```sh
Atom.         L ::= Ident;
AtomN.        L ::= N ;
AtomC.        L ::= C ;
AtomD.        L ::= D ;
AtomI.        L ::= I ;
AtomE.        L ::= E ;
Negation.     N ::= "(" "-" L ")";
Conjuction.   C ::= "(" L "&" L ")";
Disjuction.   D ::= "(" L "|" L ")";
Implication.  I ::= "(" L "=>" L ")";
Equivalence.  E ::= "(" L "<=>" L ")";
```

in addition to getting rid of the numbers at the ends of the labels to make it work. I am now able to parse simple sentences in predicate logic:

```sh
$ echo "(a&(a<=>b))" | ./Testlogic 

Parse Succesful!

[Abstract Syntax]
(AtomC [(Conjuction (Atom ["a"]) (AtomE [(Equivalence (Atom ["a"]) (Atom ["b"]))]))])

[Linearized Tree]
(a  & (a <=> b))
```

Answer (score 0):

The first non-terminal is considered the entry point of the parser, unless you declare the entrypoint(s) with the `entrypoint` directive.  This explains why **Edit 3** did not work yet.